# Bindings Not Updating without Specific DataContext

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm-light

I have a MVVM Light View Model with a ListBox bound to a List<>.  The Listbox gets populated initially just fine, but when I change to a different list at runtime (not just adding items), it does not get updated unless I set the specific Data context.

So this works:

```
...
DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
```

But this doesn't:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModel.MyList}"/>
```

In both cases, I can step through the set call to verify that the RaisePropertyChanged method is being called properly, but in the second case, an associated "get" never happens.

Is this working as designed, or is this a bug in MVVM-Light or possibly Silverlight?

Locator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        private static UnityContainer Container;

        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            Container = new UnityContainer();

            Container.RegisterType<MainViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        }       

        public MyViewModelType MyViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return Container.Resolve<MyViewModelType>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code snippet for your Locator class and your View-Model. Chances are the issue is there.

Comment: Seems to be a binding/notification problem. MVVM Light IMHO has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I have replicated your situation and both binding scenarios work fine. Can you also post the ViewModel? Your initial binding to a singleton looks ok so far, so the problem is likely in the Binding, but I need to repro.